# Changing what is loaded by a nib file

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, nib

in my iPad application I have a panel of buttons, I have used an `UIImageView` as this panel and put buttons on top of it and created my nib file. in some views some button of this panel should not be displayed. so what i do is removing those buttons and decreasing the height of the panel (a `UIImageView`) then reposition the button to take up the space of the removed button. I have created outlets to all of these.

Is this the way to do this? My problem is if I want to change the order my buttons are displayed at some point I can't do it by simply changing the nib file. I'll have to do some changes in the code as well.

Comment: your question is not clear, you should also provide some code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case don't use the nib to position the buttons in the first place.  It sounds like this is one of the occasional cases where you would be better off working solely from code.

Instead of having to worry about some sort of abstraction that protects your layout if you decide to reposition the buttons and about removing and repositioning buttons, you can just do the layout at runtime once your particular view knows what buttons it needs.  Your code is already doing much of the work of layout already (removing and repositioning).